# Windows 10 Out of Memory

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, memory, windows-explorer

I have a Windows 10, fully updated, PC with 16GB RAM.

Yesterday I decided to clean my Recycle Bin; I have a backup program that versions files, and so the bin was cluttered with small copies of files that change daily. In the end, there were some 35,000 deleted files.

For starters, the behaviour of the Explorer window was really sluggish (say, a full minute to re-sort the file list, for example), and because I wanted to check that I didn't permanently delete some files I care about, I was deleting by groups of say some 5,000 files.

After deleting three groups, the OS displayed an "out of memory" message; it was not the usual "please close some programs" message, but in rather in this case the message said that the OS would start closing programs on its own. And, indeed, it "closed" Chrome (it actually killed it, as all history had been lost when I restarted it later). I checked with the Task Manager, and indeed Explorer was taking 15.9GB out of 16GB of RAM. Besides Chrome, a bit later the screens went black, came back briefly with lower resolution, and then came back with normal resolution but not recognizing the second monitor (i.e., the video driver crashed).

After restarting the system, everything went back to normal (with the exception of all the tabs and history in Chrome that were lost), but I'm curious about the operating system's behaviour in all of this.

**Questions:**

- Does it really make sense to Explorer to exhaust 16GB of RAM to deal with 35,000 files in the Recycle Bin? I do have folders with that many files, and they don't cause any trouble.
- Shouldn't the OS have a mechanism to deny RAM to a program (even if it is an Explorer folder, which I have set up to launch on a separate process) instead of letting it crash the system?

Comment: explorer has issues dealing with thousands of files.

Comment: Possibly. But, for instance, I currently have a folder with 18,770 files in it, and Explorer's footprint in RAM is 46.5MB. From there to 15.9GB for twice the files, it feels a bit out of proportion. Besides the poor handling of memory, which has nothing to do that.

Comment: disable thumbnail creation in explorer options

Comment: @magicandre1981: besides the fact that thumbnails show fine in my photos  folder, with 20,000+ photos, how would it make a difference in the Recycle Bin, where 34,000 of my 35,000 files where .txt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does it really make sense to Explorer to exhaust 16GB of RAM to deal with 35,000 files in the Recycle Bin? I do have folders with that many files, and they don't cause any trouble.

Recycle Bin is different, because it maintains additional data, which needs to get parsed and presented in custom views:

> A hidden file called info2 (info in Windows 95 without the Windows Desktop Update) stores the file's original path and original name in binary format.[7] Since Windows Vista, the "meta" information of each file is saved as $I. and the original file is renamed to $R..

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trash_(computing)#Microsoft_Windows

> When a file is sent to the Vista Recycle Bin, it is renamed with a pseudorandom filename beginning with $R and ending in the file's original extension; this $R file contains the file's original content. Along with the $R file, another file (beginning with $I and named to be complimentary with the $R file) is created and contains the file's date and time of deletion (file offset 16; 8 bytes) and the file's path at the time of deletion (file offset 24; variable length; in Unicode) as shown in Figure 5.41.

https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/computer-science/recycle-bin

Opening my Recycle Bin containing ~ 30'000 files currently consumes ~ 5,5 GB of RAM for Windows Explorer as well. While not as much as in your case, I have fewer files and things might depend on where files have been deleted from, influencing lengths of paths shown, consuming different memory and stuff.

So in my opinion seeing that much memory consumed in case of so many files is normal for Recycle Bin.

> Shouldn't the OS have a mechanism to deny RAM to a program (even if it is an Explorer folder, which I have set up to launch on a separate process) instead of letting it crash the system?

It's difficult to decide 1. if the process consuming so much memory is doing the correct thing for the user at all and 2. how that process will behave in future. Remember that Windows Explorer doesn't start telling Windows to consume all memory available up until a point it gets unstable, but asked for more and more memory over time up until a point Windows recognized that it has a problem **now**. At that point it notified you as the user and asked for what to do, because you are the only one who can decide.

There are different strategies of course, the OOM-killer of Linux is one. That is simply a piece of software kicking in the exact same case like for Windows, but instead of asking some user, by default that killer decides itself. Sometimes, and in your case most likely, this means that the process consuming all that memory will get killed, optionally rescuing the system that way. But that's not necessarily the case: Think of situations were you are running VMs or databases consuming lots of memory and some new process starting to consume additional, but less than the former mentioned up until a point the system runs out of resources again. Depending on the current killer-settings/implementation/... it might simply be that instead of the new process one of your large VM- or database-processes gets killed, because the killer can't know which of the processes is the most useful one to you. It only sees which processes consume a lot of memory and knows that memory is needed.

Additionally keep in mind that preserving a functional state of the OS is only one aspect of the problem as well: The OS is a slave serving you as its master in the end, trying as hard as possible to process the workloads you put at it. Up until a point were it can't anymore, but simply because by executing processes you told it to do so.